# using fetch in TypeScript results in strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, promise, fetch

i have function in TS that must return `Promise<Array<any>>`, this function uses fetch:

```
(q: any): Promise<Array<any>> => {
    return fetch('http://speedtest.net', { mode: 'no-cors' })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data: any) => [data])
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
        ;
};
```

and it results in TS compiler error: `Type 'Promise<void | any[]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any[]>'.`

[Here is link to playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20default%20one%0D%0A%2F%2F%20ts%20is%20ok%0D%0A%2F%2F%20returning%20data%3Aany%20-%3E%20Array%3Cany%3E%0D%0A(q%3A%20any)%3A%20Promise%3CArray%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20fetch('http%3A%2F%2Fspeedtest.net'%2C%20%7B%20mode%3A%20'no-cors'%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(response%20%3D%3E%20response.json())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then((data%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20data)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.catch(error%20%3D%3E%20console.error(error))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20required%20one%0D%0A%2F%2F%20ts%20is%20NOT%20ok%0D%0A%2F%2F%20returning%20%5Bdata%5D%3AArray%3Cany%3E%20-%3E%20Array%3Cany%3E%0D%0A%2F%2F%20wrapping%20data%20into%20array%20is%20only%20change%20here%0D%0A(q%3A%20any)%3A%20Promise%3CArray%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20fetch('http%3A%2F%2Fspeedtest.net'%2C%20%7B%20mode%3A%20'no-cors'%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(response%20%3D%3E%20response.json())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then((data%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20%5Bdata%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.catch(error%20%3D%3E%20console.error(error))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20possible%20fixes%20for%20required%20one%0D%0A%2F%2F%20ts%20is%20ok%0D%0A(q%3A%20any)%3A%20Promise%3CArray%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20fetch('http%3A%2F%2Fspeedtest.net'%2C%20%7B%20mode%3A%20'no-cors'%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(response%20%3D%3E%20response.json())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then((data%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20%5Bdata%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.catch(error%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.error(error)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(error)%3B%20%2F%2F%20bubbling%20is%20not%20desired%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20or%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20return%20null%3B%20%2F%2F%20while%20ok%2C%20still%20strange%2C%20that%20it%20is%20required%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B)

- if i return just `data` (not `[data]`) - it is ok for ts
- if i `throw new Error(error)` from catch block - it is ok for ts (but not for me, as don't want bubbling of error)
- if i `return null` from catch block - it is ok for ts, but why i need to do this???

PS:

- real fetch is different from provided one, here is bare minimum for reproducing my situation
- don't tell me about `mode` in fetch, i know, that `no-cors` is almost useless, returning `opaque`
- yes, i need to skip bubbling; yes, i need catch block here.
- this one is ok for TS, only difference is `data` instead of `[data]`

  ```
  (q: any): Promise<Array<any>> => {
  return fetch('http://speedtest.net', { mode: 'no-cors' })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data: any) => data)
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      ;
  };
  ```

Comment: in case of an error you are returning undefined. how about returning []?

Comment: Wait why does it accept `null` ?!

Comment: as i mentioned, even returning null is solving that, but here comes another question: why returning data from then, and returning console.log result from catch is ok, while returning [data] - breaks everything???

Comment: try it in playground i've provided - you'll see

Comment: I guess `data: any` is efficiently disabling the promise typechecking while `[data] as Array<any>` causes typechecking of the whole promise chain.

Comment: @JonasW. sounds reasonable, let me check

Comment: By the way, if you want "any type" but without the effect of suppressing type checking altogether, you can use `{}|null|undefined`, or just `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

If the fetch call fails, it'll go to the `.catch`, and then the catch needs to return something as well. Return an empty array to make sure the function *always* returns an array.

```
(q: any): Promise<Array<any>> => {
  return fetch("http://speedtest.net", { mode: "no-cors" })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => [data])
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      return []
    })
}
```

Comment: yes, and as mentioned in question even returning null solves problem, but creates question: why returning data from then, and returning console.log result from catch is ok, while returning [data] - breaks everything???

Answer (score 0):

seems [@Jonas W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-w) from comment to original question is right ([playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Idata%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20default%20one%0D%0A%2F%2F%20ts%20is%20ok%0D%0A%2F%2F%20returning%20data%3Aany%20-%3E%20Array%3Cany%3E%0D%0A(q%3A%20any)%3A%20Promise%3CArray%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20fetch('http%3A%2F%2Fspeedtest.net'%2C%20%7B%20mode%3A%20'no-cors'%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(response%20%3D%3E%20response.json())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then((data%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20data)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.catch(error%20%3D%3E%20console.error(error))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Fdefault%20one%20using%20interface%0D%0A(q%3A%20any)%3A%20Promise%3CArray%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20fetch('http%3A%2F%2Fspeedtest.net'%2C%20%7B%20mode%3A%20'no-cors'%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(response%20%3D%3E%20response.json())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then((data%3A%20Idata)%20%3D%3E%20data)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.catch(error%20%3D%3E%20console.error(error))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20required%20one%0D%0A%2F%2F%20ts%20is%20NOT%20ok%0D%0A%2F%2F%20returning%20%5Bdata%5D%3AArray%3Cany%3E%20-%3E%20Array%3Cany%3E%0D%0A%2F%2F%20wrapping%20data%20into%20array%20is%20only%20change%20here%0D%0A(q%3A%20any)%3A%20Promise%3CArray%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20fetch('http%3A%2F%2Fspeedtest.net'%2C%20%7B%20mode%3A%20'no-cors'%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(response%20%3D%3E%20response.json())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then((data%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20%5Bdata%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.catch(error%20%3D%3E%20console.error(error))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20possible%20fixes%20for%20required%20one%0D%0A%2F%2F%20ts%20is%20ok%0D%0A(q%3A%20any)%3A%20Promise%3CArray%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20fetch('http%3A%2F%2Fspeedtest.net'%2C%20%7B%20mode%3A%20'no-cors'%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(response%20%3D%3E%20response.json())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then((data%3A%20Idata)%20%3D%3E%20%5Bdata%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.catch(error%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.error(error)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20throw%20new%20Error(error)%3B%20%2F%2F%20bubbling%20is%20not%20desired%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20or%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%20%2F%2F%20while%20ok%2C%20still%20strange%2C%20that%20it%20is%20required%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B))

it looks like `data: any` in second `then` disables type checking, as if i introduce `interface` and use it instead of `any` it results in pretty same error.

thank you all for helping me =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function passed to catch returns `void`, so in case of a failure, you actually return a `Promise<void>`. You can fix it as mentioned in other answers, by returning something after logging, but this is error-prone as the caller of your function will not realise that there was an error. In some situations this might be fine, but I would suggest writing it like this:

You can write it like this:

```
(q: any): Promise<Array<any>> => {
    const promise = fetch('http://speedtest.net', { mode: 'no-cors' })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data: any) => [data]);
    promise.catch(error => console.error(error));
    return promise;
};
```

Then the caller of the code has to handle a failed promise by themselves, and can decide what to do. Or they might ignore it, and rely on some global mechanism for catching unhandled rejected promises.

Note that `console.error` is guaranteed to be called before any handling done by the caller of your method, because callbacks passed to `then` are called in the same order as the `then` calls - see https://promisesaplus.com/#point-37.